# Code works without loop but doesn't work with loop

Tags: python, loops

```
file = open("Login.txt","a")
file.write (newusername1)
file.write (",")
file.write (newpassword1)
file.write("\n")
file.close()

print("")

incorrect_credentials2=True 

while incorrect_credentials2:
    username1=input("Please enter your username: ")
    password1=input("Please enter your password: ")
    with open('Login.txt') as f:
        if username1 +","+ password1 in f.read():
            print("Logged In")
            incorrect_credentials2 = False
        else:
            print("Incorrect username or password")
            incorrect_credentials2 = True
```

This piece of code works when I remove the incorrect_credentials2 bit (the loop) but when I have it, it doesn't show in the shell. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please, include [mcve] that demonstrate the problem, not link to external site

Comment: Your 2nd if condition is outside the while loop and you are never exiting the 1st while loop. So your code is stuck there. Check below my answer for corrected code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are stuck in the first while loop. See corrected code where I added a condition on the 1st loop.
https://repl.it/repls/UnderstatedExtrasmallStrings

```
if accountmanagement == 1:
  while incorrect_credentials1:
      username1=input("Please enter your username: ")
      password1=input("Please enter your password: ")
      with open('Login.txt') as f:
        if username1 +","+ password1 in f.read():
          print("Logged In")
          incorrect_credentials1=False
        else:
          print("Incorrect username or password")
          incorrect_credentials1=True
```

Comment: thank you, that helped with both of my pieces of code

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `if accountmanagement == 2:` condition inside while loop.

```
print("Hello Player 1, you need an account to play Dice!")
print("1: Login to your account")
print("2: Create an account")
accountmanagement = int(input())

print("\n")

incorrect_credentials1= True

while incorrect_credentials1:
    if accountmanagement == 1:
        username1=input("Please enter your username: ")
        password1=input("Please enter your password: ")
        with open('Login.txt') as f:
            if username1 +","+ password1 in f.read():
                print("Logged In")
                incorrect_credentials1=False
            else:
                print("Incorrect username or password")
                incorrect_credentials1=True


    if accountmanagement == 2:
        newusername1 = input("Please enter your name: ")
        newpassword1 = input("Excellent! Now let's create a password: ")

        file = open("Login.txt","a")
        file.write (newusername1)
        file.write (",")
        file.write (newpassword1)
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
        incorrect_credentials1=False
    else:
        print("Incorrect option selected.)
        incorrect_credentials1 = False
```

Your indentation for 2nd `if` condition was outside while loop. Just make it inside and you are good to go.

Comment: This now has an infinite loop if they select 2 (it also has an infinite loop is the enter e.g. 3 for accountmanagement)

Comment: Yes that would happen because we have not considered the case if user inputs any value other than `1 and 2`. Updating answer.

Comment: Please check and let me know if any other issue arises.